# can't include devise helper methods in my controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm working on an API and we have a login via devise. Working on my controllers, I have a method in `SessionsController` like this

```
  def create
    resource = User.find_for_database_authentication(email: params[:user_email])
    return invalid_login_attempt unless resource

    if resource.valid_password?(params[:user_password])
      session[:uid] = resource.authentication_token
      #sign_in("user", resource)
      render :json => {success: true, auth_token: resource.authentication_token, email: resource.email}
      return
    end
    invalid_login_attempt
  end
```

but I got an error on `sign_in` saying that this method doesn't exists.
I tried to `include Devise::Controllers::InternalHelpers` but this doesn't worked too...
What am I missing?